# SFML Text is not drawn on the window

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using SFML with C++. The problem is that nothing is drawn on the window if I use functions, but I can draw when I make the text local. Please tell me what did I do wrong

Code:

In the game.cpp file

```
void Game::loadMenuText(sf::Font f, std::string textString, int x, int y, sf::Text *tex){

tex->setFont(f);
tex->setCharacterSize(16);
tex->setFillColor(sf::Color(0x225522ff));
tex->setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
tex->setString(textString);
tex->setPosition(x,y);
```

}

```
void Game::loadFont(){

if (!font.loadFromFile("font/arial.ttf"))
{
    std::cout<<"Font could not be loaded";
}
```

}

```
void Game::run(){
    loadFont();
    sf::Text ButtonTex;
    loadMenuText(font,"Play",20,20,&ButtonTex);
    menuText.push_back(ButtonTex);
    window.draw(menuText[0]);
```

}

in the game.hpp file

```
private:
sf::Font font;
std::vector<sf::Text> menuText;
public:
void run();
void loadFont();
void loadMenuText(sf::Font, std::string, int, int, sf::Text *tex);
```

Hopefully I did not forget to add anything

Comment: Please include definitions of your functions and of `sf::Text` as well.

Comment: 1 second I'll edit it now ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read reference about [Text](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Text.php)

> It is important to note that the sf::Text instance doesn't copy the
>   font that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it. Thus, a sf::Font
>   must not be destructed while it is used by a sf::Text (i.e. never
>   write a function that uses a local sf::Font instance for creating a
>   text).

your problem is that you are passing local variable `sf::Font f` in function `loadMenuText` to `tex` so it leads to undefined behaviour, `tex` refers to resource which was deleted.

Change your signature to:

```
void Game::loadMenuText(sf::Font& f, std::string textString, int x, int y, sf::Text *tex){    
                                 ^^^ 
 //..
```

then you will be using original `font` object instead of its copy.